# How to get my macro working on other excel sheets

Tags: vba

I pulled this code online, I am a noob, but I have made some changes to the looping. Please help me out! I want to get this macro working on other sheets, saved to the macro ribbon. I've added it as an Add-In, checked security settings, checked tools>references. The problem is if I save it as a module under the excel file I want to split, it works, but if I save it in a blank sheet and pull it as a macro, which is my goal for my team to use, the macro pulls the blank original sheet and breaks the master in half; leaving the active sheet untouched.

```
Sub Macrosplittest()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim fName As String
    Dim ShtCountBk1 As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ShtCountBk1 = IIf(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count Mod 2 = 1, Sheets.Count
  / 2 + 0.5, Sheets.Count / 2)
    Set neww = Workbooks.Add
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        i = i + 1
        If i > ShtCountBk1 Then
            fName = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
            neww.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fName & " (1).xls"
            Set neww = Workbooks.Add
            i = 1
        End If
        Sht.Copy after:=Worksheets(neww.Sheets.Count)
        If i = 1 Then
           For Each ws In Worksheets
               If ws.Name <> Sht.Name Then
                   ws.Delete
               End If
           Next ws
        End If
    Next Sht
    fName = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
    neww.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fName & " (2).xls"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you have a typo where you say "ShtCountNk1 = IIf(ActiveWorkbook...") I believe you just want "If(ActiveWorkbook...". Also, from what I can tell, you are creating a new workbook (thus activating it) and then looping through that new workbook's sheets. Is this intended? It seems odd to me since a new workbook should only have one sheet. What are you trying to accomplish with this code? It is hard to see your goal.

Comment: http://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-iif-function.html > I was told IIF was a nested function. My goal is to split a big file with say 200 sheets, into two 100 sheets. The total usually varies, sometimes it's 210, 222, 255, depends on the data we receive.

Comment: I see now, I had no clue that even existed. I learned something new! I posted a modified version of your code, but I am not sure that this will do it if you are simply splitting the files in half. Do you need to split Odd's and evens? For example with 6 sheets does it have to be (1, 3, 5) and (2, 4, 6) or can it be (1, 2, 3) (4, 5, 6) that are being sent to the new workbook?

Comment: Thanks, I will run that code and see. No, I just need to split it right down the middle for size purposes. I also need my team of analysts to do have access to do the same. it's because we upload the files into a sharepoint and the files are too large to upload

Comment: If the code I posted doesnt work I should be able to come up with something that does the task. Not needing it to be split a certain way should make it relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think I see what you are trying to do:

```
Sub Macrosplittest()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Dim Sht As Worksheet
        Dim fName As String
        Dim ShtCountBk1 As Integer
        Dim ws As Worksheet

        Dim wbActive as Workbook

        Dim newBook as Workbook

        Dim lHolder as Long
        Dim sHolder as String

        Dim i as Long

        Set wbActive = ActiveWorkbook

        lHolder = wbActive.Sheets.Count

        If lHolder Mod 2 = 1 Then
            ' This should evaluate just fine without parentheses, but I
            ' prefer to have the parentheses to make the code clear
            ShtCountBk1 = (lHolder / 2) + .05 
        Else
            ShtCountBk1 = lHolder / 2
        End IF

       Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

       For Each Sht In wbActive.Worksheets
           i = i + 1
           Sht.Name = "SHT-" & Sht.Name
           sHolder = Sht.Name

           If i > ShtCountBk1 Then
               fName = Replace(wbActive.Name, ".xls", "")
               newBook.SaveAs wbActive.Path & "\" & fName & " (1).xls"
               Set newBook= Workbooks.Add
               i = 1
           End If

           Sht.Copy after:=Worksheets(newBook.Sheets.Count)

           If i = 1 Then
              For Each ws In Worksheets
                   If ws.Name <> sHolder Then
                       ws.Delete
                   End If
               Next ws
           End If

       Next Sht

       fName = Replace(wbActive.Name, ".xls", "")
       newBook.SaveAs wbActive.Path & "\" & fName & " (2).xls"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have made some modifications to make your code easier to read, and to make it properly refer to the workbooks you are targeting. It is best to avoid `ActiveWorkbook` since this can result in errors. Also, `ThisWorkbook` will refer to the workbook running the code. I am not sure if this will properly refer to the activeworkbook when `ThisWorkbook` is called by a add-in, but it is best to err on the side of caution.

Comment: Interesting, It is so much easier to read. I'm having an issue because I get a 424 object error. it seems to be with the strings lholder and sholder.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Only sHolder is a string. lHolder is Long (a number that can store a large amount of values).

Comment: lHolder = wb.Sheets.Count

Comment: I fixed it. It is supposed to be wbActive.Sheets.Count. Also when I was testing the code I noticed something that will be important to keep in mind. If the workbook you are copying sheets from is not using named sheets, and instead you are just using "Sheet1" "Sheet2" you will want to use something to make the sheet names unique. I added a bit to the code to do this, but you can figure something out that works for your needs.

Comment: fantastic it works! that was a lot simpler when you did it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem at all :). Definitely practice with refactoring (cleaning up) your code and making it easier to read/more dynamic. Those skills go a long way!

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` always refers to the workbook/project running the code - if that's an Excel add-in, then it's referring to the add-in. Useful when your add-in has data or template sheets.

Comment: Actually I've been adapting to wsActive and wbActive more often now and it's been much better. Then setting them as activeworkbook .

Comment: Glad to hear it! Its a great practice to have. I remember when I first read the advice of avoiding "Select" and "Activate" and I thought it was impossible. Now I do absolutely everything I can to avoid referring to anything that I havent already set to a variable. It allows much more control. Not to mention the anguish caused by the times I have lost hours of work because I accidentally close the wrong workbook!